# How do I keep the Facebook Like Box from creating XHTML errors?

Tags: validation, xhtml, attributes, facebook-likebox

I am using the most current Facebook Like Box on my website. When I go to validate my site's XHTML, I am seeing that there are several errors caused by labels that are not recognized. To be specific, here is the Facebook Like Box code that I have on my site:

> div class="fb-like-box" data-href="http://www.facebook.com/aboroden"
>   data-width="360" data-height="350" data-show-faces="true" data-stream="true" data-header="false" border="0"

I am getting the following errors:

> - There is no attribute "data-href"
> - There is no attribute "data-width"
> - There is no attribute "data-height"
> - There is no attribute "data-show-faces"
> - There is no attribute "data-stream"
> - There is no attribute "data-header"
> - There is no attribute "border"

There are no errors with the script or functionality of the Like Box, but I would like my XHTML to be error free. Can someone please help me to find a way around this so that I can remove my errors but still have a functioning Like Box?

You can view my site at http://www.aboroden.com. At the bottom, I have a link to the XHTML validator. Thanks!

Comment: could you please show what element these attributes are being applied to? Why are the `data-*` attributes being used?